# UnityContainer - how register/resolve with dependency chaining

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

I have an MVC app that has `Controller` that takes a `IDomainService`.
The `DomainService` class constructor takes an `IRepository`
and the `Repository` class constructor requires a connection string.

I have something like this:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;

c.RegisterInstance("ConnectionString", connectionString);

c.RegisterType<IDepartmentRepository, DepartmentRepository>(
    "DepartmentRepository", 
    new InjectionConstructor(connectionString));

c.RegisterType<IDepartmentDomainService, DepartmentService>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IDepartmentRepository>(
            "DepartmentRepository")));
```

However, this doesn't work.

Am I do something wrong? I have no problem with the repository injection, but I can't get my domain service injected (with the repository) to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually add a small class for this:

```
public class AppConfigConnectionFactory : IConnectionFactory
{
   public IDbConnection Create() 
   { 
        return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
             .ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString);
   }
}

c.RegisterType<IConnectionFactory, AppConfigConnectionFactory>();
c.RegisterType<IDepartmentRepository, DepartmentRepository>();
```

Do not depend on strings if you do not have to. And you'll also avoid some code duplication in each repository with this solution.

Comment: I like your approach. It's very clean. +1.